# why i am getting websphere mq error code 2195 where my adapter read a messages from websphere mq

Tags: ibm-mq

i have written code for an adapter that read messages from websphere mq, but whenever adapter read a message from websphere mq, everytime it gives 2195 error code.
how can i see the exact reason for occurance of 2195

Comment: Can you provide more information? What version of WebSphere MQ are you using? is this a C application or a Java/.NET application? If it's Java/.NET please post complete exception stack.

Comment: i m using websphere mq 7.0, and it is a java application, i am getting error as "Reason '2195'" and not able to find from where it is causing this error in my code, and it comes only when the application read a message from MQ

Comment: Post the complete exception stack. Also what level of MQ v7.0 you are on? Just do a dspmqver on command prompt to get the complete version details.

Comment: Check if the channel you are using for connection is present and has necessary permissions(set MCA user).

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you post your code.

Comment: @shashi version: 7.1.0.0
level: p000-L111019
BuildType: IKAP -(Production), i am not able to find the exact code from where it is happening , so no stacktrace, only getting detail except the reason code

Comment: That's really strange. Have you put your code under a try/catch block? Put the entire block of your code in a try/catch block. MQ Java throws a MQException whenever there is an error. So you should catch that exception and print the exception. Can you show us your code that you think is throwing exception?

Comment: Any code that does not include exception handling sufficient to catch the error and print it is defective and that aspect *must* be fixed.  Can you imagine having this conversation for a production application and no way to debug it?  This is not a WebSphere-MQ problem, it should be posted as a Java coding question regarding minimal acceptable exception handling practices.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar in your classpath ? It is needed to avoid this message.