# When connecting from pymqi to IBM MQ on z/OS I am receiving MQRC 2195: MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-mq, pymqi

I'm trying to connect to MQ z/OS using PYMQI, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "davidemq.py", line 9, in <module>
    qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymqi.py", line 2431, in connect
    qmgr.connect_tcp_client(queue_manager, CD(), channel, conn_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymqi.py", line 1330, in connectTCPClient
    self.connectWithOptions(name, cd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymqi.py", line 1311, in connectWithOptions
    raise MQMIError(rv[1], rv[2])
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2195: FAILED: MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR
```

This is the code:

```py
import pymqi

queue_manager = "****"
channel = "***********"
host = "******"
port = "nnnnn"
conn_info = "%s(%s)" % (host, port)

qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback gives you the (vague) error:

`Reason 2195: FAILED: MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR`

Could be an environment/configuration error, permissions, missing something from the classpath.

See:

[why i am getting websphere mq error code 2195 where my adapter read a messages from websphere mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272399/why-i-am-getting-websphere-mq-error-code-2195-where-my-adapter-read-a-messages-f)

[How to resolve WebSphere MQ Reason code 2195 related error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687004/how-to-resolve-websphere-mq-reason-code-2195-related-error)